# Add parameters to Paypal Express Checkout Button for subscription payment

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

Is it possible to simply add parameters to the Paypal Express Checkout code - that will set up for subscription - or point to an existing subscription - already set up on my seller account?

```
payment: function(data, actions) {
return actions.payment.create({
    payment: {
        transactions: [
            {
                amount: { total: '0.11', currency: 'USD' },
                hosted_button_id: 'PAYPALS_BUTTON_ID_7KDHB44PVYQ21',
                or_maybe_subscriptio_detials: 'monthly'

            }
        ]
    }
});
```

},

You know - like you can with their regular HTML buttons:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="PAYPALS_BUTTON_ID_7KDHB44PVYQ21">
```

Or do you need to set up the subscription details dynamically through the API?

I like the pop-up and staying on your site of the Express Checkout.
But I am not sure it is worth a bunch of additional coding - when I could just send them off to PayPal with a HTML button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Express Checkout to utilize the Recurring Payment but, the integration itself consist of ;

1. Setup Payment Authorization (SetExpressCheckout)
2. Redirect Customer to Authorization
3. Obtain Customer Details
4. Create Recurring Profiles.

It does not shared same dock just like WPS button you use to know.

Basically in SetExpressCheckout you would need to add below parameter ;

```
&L_BILLINGTYPE0=RecurringPayments    #The type of billing agreement
&L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0=RecurringPaymentWithEC    #The description of the billing agreement
```

It would be set as ;

```
Endpoint URL: https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
HTTP method: POST
POST data:
USER=insert_merchant_user_name_here
&PWD=insert_merchant_password_here
&SIGNATURE=insert_merchant_signature_value_here
&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
&VERSION=86
&L_BILLINGTYPE0=RecurringPayments    #The type of billing agreement
&L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0=RecurringPaymentWithEC    #The description of the billing agreement
&cancelUrl=https://example.com/cancel    #For use if the consumer decides not to proceed with payment
&returnUrl=https://example.com/success   #For use if the consumer proceeds with payment
```

After user is redirect, then the buyer need to provide an authorization for being charged with a specific terms.

After that call the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileAPI

```
Endpoint URL: https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
HTTP method: POST
POST data:
USER=insert_merchant_user_name_here
&PWD=insert_merchant_password_here
&SIGNATURE=insert_merchant_signature_value_here
&METHOD=CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile
&VERSION=86
&TOKEN=insert_token_value_here
&PAYERID=payer_id_value   #Identifies the customer's account
&PROFILESTARTDATE=2012-05-11T00:00:00Z    #Billing date start, in UTC/GMT format
&DESC=RecurringPaymentWithEC    #Profile description - same as billing agreement description
&BILLINGPERIOD=Month    #Period of time between billings
&BILLINGFREQUENCY=1    #Frequency of charges
&AMT=10    #The amount the buyer will pay in a payment period
&CURRENCYCODE=USD    #The currency, e.g. US dollars
&COUNTRYCODE=US    #The country code, e.g. US
&MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS=3    #Maximum failed payments before suspension of the profile
```

In response you'll get

```
PROFILEID=I-6D5UGCVX1234
&PROFILESTATUS=ActiveProfile
&ACK=Success
...
```

Comment: I think I have a similar issue to OP and have implemented it with javascript for one time payments and it works fine. What you have given here is not Javascript though? I'm not even sure where I would put / use this code?